# Problemas com API JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que envolve música e, para facilitar o desenvolvimento, estou utilizando a API [RetroJS](https://github.com/eshiota/retro-audio-js). Porém, não estou conseguindo utilizá-la. Aparecem o seguintes erros no Console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="src/Chord.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Controls.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Events.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Instrument.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Note.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Player.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Song.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Track.js"></script>
    <script src="src/instruments/Oscillator.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/module.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/namespace.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/sushi/extend.js"></script>
    <script>
        function play(){
            let player = new Player();

            var minhaSingelaCancao = JSON.stringify({
                title : "mi-mi-re-do",
                tempo : 60,
                time_signature : "4/4",
                score : [{
                    instrument : "oscillator-sine",
                    volume : 1.0,
                    sheet : "EEDCCDEFGGFEEDD".split('')
                }]
            });

            player.load(minhaSingelaCancao);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei de testar e verifiquei vários outros erros, vamos por parte.

> 1. Module is not defined

Esse erro é porque você está carregando o script `vendor/module.js` depois do `Chord.js`, `Controls.js`, `Events.js` e etc.

Como essas outras libs precisam do `module.js`, não vai funcionar.

Mova esse trecho `<script src="vendor/module.js"></script>` para o topo (O primeiro da lista).

> 2. Uncaught ReferenceError: Player is not defined at play (index.html:19) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:37)

Você deve substituir `let player = new Player();` por

`var player = new Retro.Player();` ou `var player = new App.Player();`

*Acabou por aí? Não. Seu código precisa de mais reparos.*

Após corrigir os erros acima, você irá se deparar com erros desse tipo:

> Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Por quê? Como corrigir?

Pois bem, para utilizar essa lib, você precisa seguir algumas regras, uma delas é definir **exatamente** o trecho abaixo em seu HTML.

```
<div data-player-controls style="display:none">
  <div data-song-controls>
    <span data-song-load></span>
  </div>

  <div class="playback-controls" data-playback-controls>
      <button type="button" class="bt play-bt" data-play>Play</button>
      <button type="button" class="bt pause-bt" data-pause>Pause</button>
      <button type="button" class="bt stop-bt" data-stop>Stop</button>
  </div>

  <div data-song-info>
    <span data-current-song></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Isso é porque ao instanciar o objeto `Player`, ele tentará localizar os elementos acima, caso não encontre, você terá uma falha e não conseguir prosseguir.

*Espera que tem mais*

Corrigindo todos esses erros acima, você ainda terá dois outros erros. Dessa vez com a execução da música.

Um dos erros é porque você está tentando passar uma string para o método `Player.load()`. Esse método aceita apenas `json`, por isso você **não deve** utilizar `JSON.stringify();`

O segundo erro é porque as seguintes notas:
`["E", "E", "D", "C, "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "G", "F", "E", "E", "D", "D"]`
Mas se você dá uma olhada na documentação (ou no próprio código), você *deve* seguir esse padrão.

`[ "C.4", "D.4", "E.4", "F.4", "G.4", "A.4", "B.4", "C5.4" ]`

> Talvez seja bom revisar esse código, pois seguindo o Google Chrome, ele poderá ficar obsoleto https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5287995770929152

**Links Úteis:**

**[Retro Audio JS](https://github.com/eshiota/retro-audio-js)**

**[Ver funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/valdeirpsr/b2041yps/)**

Comment: Sumiram todos os erros, exceto este: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Player is not defined
    at play (index.html:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:37)"

Comment: Utilize `new Retro.Player();` ao invés de `new Player();`

Comment: index.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: Retro is not defined
    at play (index.html:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:37)

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Adicionei algumas informações + uma demo.